# Wordpress - plug-in functions is available in templates but not available to other plug-ins

Tags: php, scope, wordpress

Case:

Plugin A specifies a function that can be called in a WP template.

But, calling this same function from within the code of Plugin B yields the error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function...

I'm assuming the problem has to do with includes and/or scope, but far have not been able to find  an answer. Simply requiring or including the Plugin A php file that contains the desired function yields "Redeclaration" errors in it (the Plugin A php file).

Answer (score 1):

If plugin **B** relies on functions from plugin **A**, you could start your plugin **B** code in an init function called when all active plugins have been loaded using the `plugins_loaded` action in **WordPress**.

You can find a list of actions [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

This example assumes you're writing your plugins using classes:

**In plugin B:**

```
function __construct() {
    add_action( 'plugins_loaded', array( $this, 'init' ) );
}

function init() {
    // functions from plugin A will be available from this point on
}
```